# Ruby on Rails 5.1 from helper_method can not get Data in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new in RoR and i am using `helper_method` to pass data from ActiveRecord. My code is follow:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :main_menus


  def main_menus
    @main_menus = Category.all
  end
end
```

View: `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper-inner">

        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <%= render 'layouts/menu' %>

        <%= yield(:body) %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= render 'layouts/javascript' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Menu.html.erb:

```
<%= main_menus.all do |menu| %>
    <%= menu.title %>
<% end %>
```

Showing only this:

```
#<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f1c0e26c3d0>
```

Pls help me. Where is my error?

Comment: The `#<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f1c0e26c3d0>` is being printed because you're using `<%= ... %>` in `<%= main_menus. ... %>`. If there's nothing else being printed did you check you have records for the Category model?

Comment: In database two recodes have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're using `all` to apparently iterate over the returned value in the `main_menus` helper, which I guess should be `each`, otherwise `all` would be the equivalente to chain `.all` to `Category.all`.

Try instead:

```
<% main_menus.each do |menu| %>
  <%= menu.title %>
<% end %>
```

Note you can simplify the helper method to just return `Category.all` if you're not going to use the `@main_menus` variable.